# How can I make an if statement to determine what array to use in a tableView?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, if-statement

Using xcode 9.4, Swift 4 and ios 11, I want to select an item from a collection view screen that goes to a table view screen. On the table view screen, I have a series of arrays and, depending on what I've chosen on the collection view screen, I want to display a specific array on the table view screen.

I've already set up the `prepareForSegue` function on the collection view screen that references a var on the table view, but I'm a bit stuck on the "select an array" bit. I'm pretty sure it involves an if statement, but I'm not sure how or where to put this if statement.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the if statement that I made (I don't know if its correct):

```
    if cellItem == "jeans" {
        tableArray.append(jeanArray[])
    } else if cellItem == "skirts" {
        tableArray.append(skirtArray[])
    }
```

Then in the functions for the table set up, I've referenced `tableArray`.

Comment: Your collection view and table view are in the same controller or not?

Comment: @KTang Thanks for getting back to me so quickly. They're in separate controllers. I have 6 categories in the collection view and corresponding hard-coded arrays in the table view.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways you can do this, I'm guessing the arrays contain similar information (guessing from jeans and skirts its clothing).

I would have a single value for determining which product type is to be displayed, then you have a few options available....

```
enum TableMode {
   case jeans, skirts, trousers, hats
}
```

The multiple products array way (not recommended)

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var tableMode: TableMode

    func tableView(UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection: Int) -> Int {
       switch tableMode {
           case .jeans:
              return jeansArray.count
           /// and so on...
       }
    }
}
```

Another option would be to have a single array that will be used, just fill it with the correct data: (best method)

```
// the int value could be the category ID from your API 
enum TableMode: Int {
   case jeans = 13
   case skirts = 2
   trousers = 4
   hats = 19
}

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
     var tableMode: TableMode
     var products: [Products]()

     override viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad() 
         // fetch all data from api/database where categoryId = .tableMode value
         self.products = coreDataFetchResult
         self.tableView.reloadData()
     }
```

Last idea, fetch all products and just filter it as needed to show the current product type selection

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
     var tableMode: TableMode
     var products: [Products]()

     override viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad() 
         // fetch all data from core data
         self.products = coreDataFetchResult.filter { $0.categoryId = self.tableMode }
         self.tableView.reloadData()
     }
```

The best option depends on where you are filling the arrays from. I wouldn't suggest having multiple arrays if you are only going to use one.

Comment: Thanks @Scriptable for your help. I have 6 categories in the collection view and corresponding hard-coded arrays in the table view that aren't part of an API. The arrays are more offshoots of a struct than arrays, for example if I chose jeans or shoes, the names of the different shoes or jeans will come up with their pictures in the table depending what I picked. I'm sorry for my lack of knowledge, I'm still new to this.

Comment: The top option in my answer should work for you then or referring to the third option, just set products to to required array `if tableMode == .jeans { products = jeansArray }`

Comment: Thank you so much @Scriptable for all of your help. I will give it a try, Regards, Lilly.